# C++ string parsing delimited by 0's

Tags: c++, string

I have a number/string like this ( I am not sure how to convert int to and from strings)

000000122310200000223340000700012220000011411000000011011271043334010220001127100003333201000001000070005222500233400000000000000000000

What I need to do is to separate the numbers between 0's, so I get strings like

"12231"
"22334"
"7"
"1222"

and so forth, and then I need to convert them into int.
(basically I have searched to no avail of how to do the conversion)

Can someone help out?

Thanks!

Comment: If it's a string you can check for each character whether it's a number other than `0` or not.

Comment: I am still a bit surprised from your question... I do not know where the data come from but are you sure that no number that you want to extract will contain a 0. if for example you have 101 are you sure that this is 1,1 and not really 101?

Comment: Is it possible to avoid vector as much as possible? I am not there yet.

Comment: Oh I am absolutely sure 0's are delimiters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) reading until '0':

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e17f386d96c8b28)

```
// First create a string stream with you input data
std::stringstream ss("000000122310200000223340000700012220000011411000000011011271043334010220001127100003333201000001000070005222500233400000000000000000000");;

// Then use getline, with the third argument it will read untill zero character
// is found. By default it reads until new line.
std::string line;
while(std::getline(ss, line, '0')) {

    // In case there are no data, two zeros one by one, skip this loop
    if ( line.empty() )
       continue;

    // now parse found data to integer
    // Throws excepions if bad data, consult: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol
    int n = std::stoi(line);
   std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @MichaelC I have added comments

Comment: I am trying to run your code, but i am getting 2 compiler errors: ss is incomplete type and std::getline is incorrectly overloaded?

Comment: @MichaelC click the live link above, you probably miss correct includes

Answer (score 2):

`std::getline`  takes an optional separator. Normally that would be a newline character (hence getline) but you could use `0`.

Answer (score 1):

If C++11 is good for you, than this should work

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<int> split(const std::string& s, char delim)
{
    std::vector<int> res;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string sub;
    while (std::getline(ss, sub, delim)) 
    {
        int val = std::stoi(sub);  // c++11
        res.push_back(val);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate from the string and check if it's '0' or not.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   char a[] = "000000122310200000223340000700012220000011411000000011011271043334010220001127100003333201000001000070005222500233400000000000000000000";
   vector<int> nums;

   int tmp = 0;
   for(int i=0;a[i];i++) {
       if(a[i] != '0') {
          tmp *= 10;
          tmp += a[i]-'0';
       } else {
          if(tmp != 0){
              nums.push_back(tmp);
              tmp = 0;
          }
       }
   }

   for(int i=0;i<nums.size();i++)
      cout << nums[i] << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> split(const std::string& x, char separator)
{
    std::stringstream stream(x);
    std::vector<int> numbers;
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(stream, line, separator)) {
        if (!line.empty()){
            int n = std::stoi(line);
            numbers.push_back(n);
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

int main()
{
    std::string myStringValue("000000122310200000223340000700012220000011411000000011011271043334010220001127100003333201000001000070005222500233400000000000000000000");
    std::vector<int> values = split(myStringValue,'0');
    for(auto i : values) {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```